# Binding a function to a Tkinter text entry field

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an address book using TKinter. I have entry fields for 'name, age, phone ect.' with text inside each one indicating what each one is.  So in the name entry field, it says 'enter name'.  What I want is so that when someone clicks in the Name entry field to begin typing, it deletes the text that's currently in there.  I know I need to make a function to clear this entry and then bind that to the entry field, but I'm stuck.

You can see what I was trying to do with 'def clearEvent' at the bottom and trying to bind that to TextField.  Is my problem that the def clearEvent function is below everything else and needs to be at the top?  Or did I make some other mistake?

```
from Tkinter import *
import sqlite3

class Hello():
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame=Frame(master, width=80, height=50)
        frame.pack()
        self.text = Label(frame, text="               ")
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.grid(row=0, sticky=W)

        self.lab = Label(frame, text="name")
        self.lab.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.lab.grid(row=1)

        self.TextField = Entry(frame, text = "name", width=30)
        self.TextField.insert(0, "Enter Name")
        self.TextField.pack()
        self.TextField.grid(row=1)
        self.TextField.bind("<Enter>", clearEvent)

        self.TextField2 = Entry(frame, text = "age", width=30)
        self.TextField2.insert(0, "Enter Age")
        self.TextField2.pack()
        self.TextField2.grid(row=2)

        self.TextField3 = Entry(frame, text = "phone", width=30)
        self.TextField3.insert(0, "Enter Phone #")
        self.TextField3.pack()
        self.TextField3.grid(row=3)

        self.TextField4 = Entry(frame, text = "fblink", width=30)
        self.TextField4.insert(0, "Enter Facebook Link")
        self.TextField4.pack()
        self.TextField4.grid(row=4)

        self.btn=Button(frame, text='Add', command=self.add_note)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn.grid(row=5, rowspan=1, sticky="w")

        self.showbtn = Button(frame, text='Update', command=self.show_notes)
        self.showbtn.pack()
        self.showbtn.grid(row=5, rowspan=1, sticky="")

        self.delbtn = Button(frame, text='Delete', command=self.del_notes)
        self.delbtn.pack()
        self.delbtn.grid(row=5, rowspan=1, sticky="e")


        self.content=Listbox(master, width=50)
        self.content.pack()

    def clearEvent(self, event):
        self.TextField.delete(0,END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Enter>` event is fired when the mouse enters the widget. You said you want to clear it when the user clicks in the widget, which is a different event. You should be binding to `<1>`, which will fire when the user clicks the left mouse button in the widget. Even better, bind to the `<FocusIn>` event, which will fire whenever the focus moves to that widget, whether by a click or whether by the user pressing tab.

However, I think you'll realize that this is not going to give the user a good experience. What if they fill in the form, then realize they made a spelling mistake in one of the fields? They click in the field to edit it and BOOM! whatever was there is gone and they have to re-type the whole field.

You might want to re-think this plan. For example, when there is placeholder text, you might want the foreground color to be a light gray. Then, in your function you first check to see what the color is. If it's black, do nothing. it's light gray, delete the text and then make sure you set the color to black, so the next time the user clicks, the text isn't removed.

Comment: I put <focusin> and now it says global name "NameError": clearEvent is not defined

Comment: @user2897013: well, based on your code, `clearEvent` _is_ undefined. There's a `self.clearEvent`, however.

Answer (score 0):

You have binded your text field with **ENTER** rather than mouse click.
Everything else seems fine